# XeLaTeX on Mac OSX: Using User Fonts

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mac

I recently started using XeLaTeX on Mac OSX, and was not able to get XeLaTeX to recognize the fonts that I had installed. After opening Font Book, bringing up the Preferences dialog, and opting to install the fonts into the system-level directory (`/System/Library/Fonts`) instead of the user-level directory (`~/Library/fonts`), everything worked well.

However, I prefer not to mix the fonts that I download with the fonts that come with the operating system. In the future, I may also wish to have XeLaTeX use fonts in arbitrary directories on my system (say, some subdirectory within a local Git repository). I am very naively guessing that the reason XeLaTeX is not finding my user-level fonts is that they are not in the OS font cache. However, invoking `fc-cache` on my user-level font directory still does not update the output I get from `fc-list` with my User fonts.

So, here's my question: how can I get XeLaTeX to use TTF and OTF fonts located in arbitrary directories on my system? Currently, I can only get XeLaTeX to work with System fonts.

Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`fontspec` allows setting a path to specific fonts which are not in the current search path (or installed system-wide). This example uses `SpecialFont.ttf` just after downloading it:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}

\setmainfont[Path=/Users/username/Downloads/]{SpecialFont.ttf}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -- thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

@hakaze's answer helped me a lot. I still needed to add some parameters so that every variation can be found:

```
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif}[Path = input/fonts/,
                              Extension = .otf,
                              UprightFont = *-Regular,
                              BoldFont = *-Bold,
                              ItalicFont = *-Italic,
                              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
                              Ligatures=TeX
                             ]
```

as described in fontspec's [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).

The input/fonts/ folder contains:

```
LibertinusSerif-BoldItalic.otf
LibertinusSerif-Bold.otf
LibertinusSerifDisplay-Regular.otf
LibertinusSerifInitials-Regular.otf
LibertinusSerif-Italic.otf
LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf
LibertinusSerif-SemiboldItalic.otf
LibertinusSerif-Semibold.otf
```