# How can I install and use fonts for Mac?

Tags: xetex

Glad to see you all! I would like to know how to find, install, and use fonts for my mac system.

(1) MacOS Mojave version 10.14.1

(2) TeXShop version 4.15 (Compile by XeLaTeX)

(3) The following content do not produce a good result because of Chinese letters (宮 and 內). This is really serious because my file surely will includes many Chinese letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
Chongning Canon 崇寧藏. \\ In the Taishō Canon, it is called the `Old Song Edition belonging to the Library of the Imperial Household' 宮內省圖書寮本 (舊宋本) and is abbreviated as 宮.          
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I manage this problem? I'm a genuine novice to use TeXShop system in Mac. I would be most glad if you kindly share some instructions with regard to finding fonts, install, and use in the example.

With metta.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70364/xelatex-on-mac-osx-using-user-fonts?rq=1

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Your link is really helpful. I would like to ask one thing again. I would like to use xeCJK. But I don't know how to install. I visited the website (https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk?lang=en) and download zip, and open the file. Unfortunately, I can not go forward from that point. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install MacTeX? Recently? If so you should already have the xeCJK package. To see the Chinese documentation for xeCJK by using the Help->Show Help for Package… item in TeXShop, entering xeCJK and pressing Return.

Comment: Thank you Herb Schulz! With your kind help, I was able to open xeCJK.pdf. But my tex was stopped by "\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}". So I suppose this line is related to the main point. Could you share some more information with regard to this? Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like your MacTeX does not find the font SimSun. Are you also sure your texshop compiling engine is set to 'xelatex', and not `latex`?

Comment: Thank you sztruks! As you pointed out, my TeXShop was set to use "XeLaTeX" instead of "LaTeX". Then, how can I make the program find SimSun font? Thank you very much again!

Comment: Where is the font SimSum? Did you install it? Does Font Book find it? What kind of font is it (otf, tt, etc.)?

Comment: Dear Herb Schulz, thank you for your comment. I found "help" => Show help for Package ... item in TeXShop. After entering xeCJK, and pressing Return, my mac shows the "xeCJK.pdf" as you instructed. I found the first example of page 2 (基本用法), and tried it as follows. However it was not successful because of "\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}". That's why I enrolled a question yesterday. The original settings of page 2 (xeCJK.pdf) are as follows.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
中文\LaTeX 示例。
\end{document}