# XeLaTeX on macOS: How to use already installed user fonts?

Tags: fontspec, mac

After researching this for a while, as well as coming across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70364/xelatex-on-mac-osx-using-user-fonts), I'm left confused.

Is the the approach of having to hard-link a font

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=/Users/herrbischoff/Library/Fonts/]{Geomanist-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

really the only way to get XeLaTeX to recognize the fonts in the user folder? The above example works as is.

However, when I try to use them as shown in most guides, either using the family name

```
\setmainfont{Geomanist}
```

or the Postscript name

```
\setmainfont{Geomanist-Regular}
```

always yields the error

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Geomanist" cannot be found
```

or

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Geomanist-Regular" cannot be found
```

respectively.

I cannot imagine it to be the only solution as it feels very clumsy. System fonts can be used as expected but not the ones in the user folder `/Users/<user>/Library/Fonts`, which is where FontBook.app installs fonts to and has been the default folder for user fonts on macOS for 20+ years now.

Any ideas how I can permanently include all fonts from the user folder for use in my TeX documents?

Comment: `Extension=.otf` ... Please google without mac request

Comment: @koleygr, this doesn't answer my question at all. And yes, I usually Google without Mac specifics first. It's not a question of missing extension but of having to specify the path in *every* document. My question is if having to specify a font path in the document is the only way to make things work. My first example works as is for me.

Comment: I don't have a mac but try https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461396/2388

Answer (score 1):

I assume the Geomanist-Regular.otf font is in your ~/Library/Fonts folder as suggested in your call above. First: there is no need to give that path since xetex gets the fonts by name from the OS. If it appears in Font Book it will be found by the font name given there. To use fonts that are not in standard locations used by the OS, e.g., fonts supplied by you TeX Distribution, you need to give the file name rather than the font name.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The entire point of my question is that the behaviour you describe does not work for me. I take from your response that it *should* work but doesn't. In that case, I'm very interested in troubleshooting options.

Comment: @herrbischoff : what part(s) of the answer above doesn't work?

Comment: Leaving the path name out results in the given error message. You claim it should work. The fonts are not found when they apparently should. I stated as much in my question. At this point, I'm unsure about how I can be any clearer.